# Advanced network

Tags: networking, network-programming

There is no user authentication in SMTP. Such that, anyone (without logging-in) can send e-mails. What would be the foremost (most important) problem if a user-authentication mechanism is implemented in STP?

Comment: *"There is no user authentication in SMTP"* – [wat?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Practically all SMTP servers in MSA role use AUTH LOGIN. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_submission_agent